# Font size weirdly changes on Chrome mobile browser inside flex container

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, flexbox

I noticed a weird behavior when I open my website in mobile Chrome (version 116 and below). Sometimes the font size in a flex container shrinks for no apparent reason. I boiled down the situation to this simple HTML:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
</head>
<body>
  <p style="display: flex;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Sapiente nobis, laudantium magni doloremque vitae quisquam nesciunt veritatis id voluptatum laboriosam.</p>
</body>
</html>
```

When opened on mobile Chrome, it looks like this:

[image]

This does not ever happen on desktop, in developer tools when testing mobile layout, in mobile or desktop Firefox, nowhere besides just the mobile Chrome. I am completely perplexed by this. I tried playing with `text-size-adjust`, tried setting hard `font-size` on every element, nothing helps.

Does anybody have an idea what might be happening?

Comment: Tested your code on Google Chrome, Android, and it doesn't do this. Perhaps the browser has cached an old version? Perhaps some font size setting in the browser?

Comment: Thanks for testing it. I tried this on different domains and different websites of mine, so cache is not the reason. I try to google if there are some font settings in Chrome.

Comment: I'm having the same problem on my Google Pixel 5a with changes we're making on our website. It looks like a problem in Chrome: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=877833. I've seen workarounds mentioned in various places, but none of them have helped.

Answer (score 0):

Try to put the p inside a div style="display: flex;"  because the way you wrote, you are only applying display flex to the first p, not for both